# How to read .xpt.zip file into R using a connection

Tags: r

Does anyone have a fast/direct method for reading a SAS XPT file from within a ZIP file into R?

For example:

```
> library(foreign)
> d = read.xport(unz('foo.zip','bar.xpt'))
Error in lookup.xport(file) : first argument must be a file name
```

I could `unzip()` each file first, apply `read.xport()` to the unzipped XPT file, and then delete the XPT file, but this seems unnecessarily slow.

Comment: You can try using my rio package from Github: https://www.Github.com/leeper/rio. It should do this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Using `rio` from the CRAN I get `Error in .guess(file, format) : Filename is not a string`. I had trouble installing the required dependencies for `install_github("leeper/rio")` to work in R2.15.1 and R3.0.1 so I wasn't able to try the development version.

Comment: The CRAN version is outdated and won't work for this. Sorry.